# Would Drones.SE benefit from enabling MathJax?

Tags: feature-request, mathjax

[MathJax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MathJax) is a library that provides maths formatting, and this has been implemented across mathematical SE sites.

Would it be a good idea to enable MathJax on Drones.SE? E.g. for answers such as [this one](https://drones.stackexchange.com/a/323/72).

(As per metas, upvote for yes and downvote otherwise.)

Comment: is there any disadvantage to doing so?

Comment: ZOMG, why is this being voted down? We can't have drones at all without heavy math that is unique to drone flight. The core automation which allows them to fly is a domain of intense interest and is done by exactly the kind of experts I'd like to see attracted to SE.Drones.

Comment: As this has been sitting at a majority for Yes for over a month now, it may be a good time to go about getting MathJax enabled?

Comment: I'll ping a CM to try and get this enabled

Comment: I made an answer of the posts that would benefit from this, please add some more if you find any :)

Answer (score 7):

So long as there is no disadvantage to doing so, I say that **Yes**, it should be enabled.

While Daniil states "We will have very few answers with that math technical detail", I think that this is the wrong way to run a SE site. Answers must be professional and high quality, which induces technical by default.

Answer (score 6):

There are a couple of answers where I would actually be able to benefit from that - it's going to be abnormal to really need/benefit from it, but where it is useful, those are going to be high quality showcase sorts of answers.

If nothing is lost by enabling, enable.

Answer (score 6):

Examples of posts that will benefit from MathJax (feel free to add more):

- [Why do multirotors usually have four propellors?](https://drones.stackexchange.com/a/323)
- [How does a quadcopter yaw?](https://drones.stackexchange.com/a/419)
- [Do aerodynamics scale for model aircraft?](https://drones.stackexchange.com/a/1234)
- [How to measure the pitch of a propeller?](https://drones.stackexchange.com/a/1156)
- [Determining the mAh of 4S battery for a 3 inch drone](https://drones.stackexchange.com/a/1149)
- [Calculating the range of an FPV drone](https://drones.stackexchange.com/a/839)
- [Can I mount my RX and VTX antennae next to one another?](https://drones.stackexchange.com/a/1339)

Answer (score 2):

We got it on Materials Modeling since Day 1 of Private Beta. I don't see any disadvantage to it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it will. We will have very few answers with that math technical detail, so I do not think it is necessary for very few answers.

Comment: Can I disagree? I think we've already had a fair number which already have math showing up in them. We're far away from SE.Mathematics, but the drone domain is at its core a question of controls and automation, which are exclusively mathematical in nature. It's really annoying to have to make the math somewhere else, make a PNG, and then return here. Worse, if you made a mistake our would otherwise like to update things, you have to either save the original MatmML code or rewrite it all.