# Let's get MathJax enabled on this site!

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, mathjax

Just after this site started, this question was asked:

- [Would Drones.SE benefit from enabling MathJax?](https://drones.meta.stackexchange.com/q/75/149)

The general consensus is "yes", we should enable MathJax. There are [quite a few posts that would benefit from this](https://drones.meta.stackexchange.com/a/180/149).

Can a CM enable this please?

Comment: Yes PLEASE! I don't believe we're the only two who want this.

Comment: Acknowledging the request here and we'll get on processing it, so adding planned status.

Comment: @CesarM It took only a few minutes to turn on MathJax on Matter Modelling SE, as you can see here: https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3/5. Why would it take so long here?

Comment: @NikeDattani we're not currently processing any of the backlog on the status tags due to [ticket smash](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353982/we-expect-some-q3-projects-to-be-delayed). However, it looks like Nic already escalated it to our devs, so it should happen shortly.

Comment: @CesarM My point is that it takes a few minutes to turn on MathJaX, so why are you procrastinating? This is probably why there's 600 tickets in the queue. Also, switching on MathJaX was done by AdamLear, who is not one of the people listed in your Meta post about Ticket Smash.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I went through questions on Drones and Model Aircraft and realised that there are a lot of posts that contain formulas either as an image or code. I think you are correct, the site will benefit of having MathJax enabled. I submitted a request to our dev team to enable it. I hope you will have it soon!

---

**Update:** MathJax has been enabled both on the main site and here on meta. Please let us know if you see any issues.

Comment: Thanks, I hope so too

Comment: I think it is worth mentioning that it took me a few hours to inspect a dozen questions because each of them is very interesting and pleasure to read! Great job!

Comment: Thanks, @NicolasChabanovsky! MathJX will definitely make it easier to post more of those beautiful eqns. ;)

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky why did you go through the posts? Why didn't you just approve the request right away?